# User editable configurations on python module with validation

Tags: python, design-patterns, configuration

Context: I'm creating a python module for dealing with strings that contains ANSI escapes, and there's this function that uses these 'tags' to insert ANSI codes on a string

```py
>>> from colortag import csprint
>>> csprint("Hello, <world: blue; bold>")
Hello, \x1b[34;1mworld\x1b[0m
```

and i want to make the characters used in the tags (";", "<", ">", etc.) customizable, the obvious way would be to pass them as parameter, but then you would need to pass the arguments every time you use the function.

So instead i want some kind of way to store these configurations so that you would need to change something just in the beginning

```py
>>> from colortag import cstring, config
>>> config.attributes_sep = ","
>>> config.attributes_case_sentivie = False
>>> csprint("Hello <world: BLUE, BOLD>")
Hello, \x1b[34;1mworld\x1b[0m
```

Also it would need validation for the type passed.

What i tried is:

```py
class Config:
    def __init__(self):
        self._attributes_sep = ","
        self._attributes_case_sentivie = True
        # etc.
    
    @property
    def attributes_sep(self):
        return self._attributes_sep
    
    @attributes_sep.setter
    def attributes_sep(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, str):
            raise TypeError("attributes_sep must be str")
        self._attributes_case_sentivie = value
    
    @property
    def attributes_case_sensitive(self):
        return self._attributes_case_sentivie
    
    @attributes_case_sensitive.setter
    def attributes_case_sensitive(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, bool):
            raise TypeError("attributes_case_sensitive must be bool")
        self._attributes_case_sentivie = value
    
    # etc.

config = Config()
```

But the problem with this is that every time you add a new configuration, you need to add it to the `__init__` and create a setter and a getter, and it looks very repetitive. Are there alternative ways to do it?